# RegEx for an S followed by 6 digits

Tags: regex

I am using Visual Studio File search with a regular expression to find an alphanumeric string of 7 characters, starting with an S or s and followed by 6 digits. For example:

s123456
S012458
s004580

Is there any easy way of searching for it?

I have already used this one, although I am not sure if it is getting everything as there are lots of files:

```
[sS]{1}\d{6}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want something such as `[sS][0-9]{6}`. The one you already have should work fine, even though you don't need the `{1}`.

Comment: @CallumWatkins..Thank you ..Just wanted to make sure as I am not a RegX person.

Comment: Turn on case-insensitive flag (usually `i`) and use `s\d{6}`

Answer (score 1):

The first remark: Your proposed regex `[sS]{1}\d{6}` contains unnecessary
`{1}`, because the default quantifier is just `{1}`.

Another remark: The "shortened" regex `[sS]\d{6}` can capture a **fragment**
of a longer word, like `xs123456` (extra chars before `s`) or `S01245856`
(more than 6 digits).

To protect against such cases, you should add a *word boundary* marker - `\b`,
both at the start and at the end of the regex.

So the final version is: `\b[sS]\d{6}\b`.